# How to compare position of employees in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i need to compare position name of all empids, if any new change in position need to display as new position change based on two latest records, i am using lag analytic function but not getting correct results ,i am beginner in sql don't know if any other functions which i can get better results could any one help me on this

[image]

Position Table  :

```
empid   postionname empseq  Date
12      ENGINEER      1     4-Apr-14
12      MANAGER       2     4-Apr-16
12      DIRECTOR      3     4-Apr-17
13      TESTER        4     4-Apr-16
13      MANAGER       5     4-Apr-17
```

OUT PUT

```
EMPID   oldpostionname  NEW POSITION
12      MANAGER     DIRECTOR
13      TESTER      MANAGER
```

Comment: everything seems to be in order and the result is logical. emp 12 used to be a manager now he's a director. same goes for emp 13

Answer (score 1):

Try as

```
SELECT empid,
         MIN (postionname) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY datecol)
            oldpostionname,
         MAX (postionname) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY datecol DESC)
            newpostionname
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT empid,
                          postionname,
                          datecol,
                          RANK () OVER (ORDER BY datecol) emprank
            FROM position_table)
   WHERE emprank >= 2
GROUP BY empid
```

**Results**

```
+-------+----------------+----------------+
| EMPID | OLDPOSTIONNAME | NEWPOSTIONNAME |
+-------+----------------+----------------+
|    12 | MANAGER        | DIRECTOR       |
|    13 | TESTER         | MANAGER        |
+-------+----------------+----------------+
```

[Demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_EXZY7AHGBWTPV77XUJQJ6IB2I.html)